Android AGP 8.4 and hilt injecting into a service
After upgrading to Android Studio Jellyfish, and updating the Android Gradle Plugin 8.4.0, on a multi-module project I can't seem to inject into my Service any more when minify in enabled.
After the upgrades, I spent quite a bit of time adding new rules to the non-app modules (they are aar modules).   I now have the app running, and most of the features working again.  But I can't get the service working.  It has quite a few things injected into it.   Since it worked with the previous version of AGP, and it works with a debug build, I assume it's due some missing rule that's needed to due the new version of AGP.   It really acts it doesn't see the annotations.   I have the same rules in this module for keeping the annotations as I do in other modules, and they are getting their injections.
I've reduced the service to:
@AndroidEntryPoint
open class MyService : Service() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var test: DTest

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Timber.d("onCreate, ${test.test}")
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}

Where DTest is in the same module and is just:
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object TestModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesDTestModule(): DTest {
        return DTest("TestModule")
    }
}

data class DTest(val test: String)

When the service is started, this is the result:
E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service my.package.MyService: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property test has not been initialized
E      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4664)
E      at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleCreateService(Unknown Source:0)
E      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2264)
E      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
E      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
E      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
E  Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property test has not been initialized
E      at my.package.MyService.onCreate(SourceFile:8)
E      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4651)
E      ... 9 more


These rules got me past the problem:
-keep class my.pkg.name.di.** { *;}
-keepclassmembers my.pkg.name.di.** { *; }
-keep class my.pkg.name.MyService* { *; }

where my.pkg.name.di is package where I keep my dagger modules
Note that the keep on the service alone didn't work, I had to add an asterisk at the end to make sure some of the hilt generated class were kept.  In fact, that was the key to getting this working.
I might be wrong, but my sense is dagger needs to update their rules for the new version of the AGP.

Thank you for sharing this issue and the solution you found. Do you have a small reproduction that you can share, then please do together with filing a bug on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788. We would be very interested in looking closer into why additional rules where required for the AGP upgrade. Also, which version where you upgrading from?
